# What is the purpose of MatchLocalNameQ?

Tags: undocumented, built-in-symbols, expression-test

I found a *kernel function* which is undocument `MatchLocalNameQ`.But I don't know the purpose of it.

```
a = 1;
b = 1;
MatchLocalNameQ[a, b]
```

> False

```
a = 1;
b = 1;
MatchLocalNameQ[a, a]
```

> True

But what want to do really this function?It's useful to us?

Comment: considering its name I'd expect it to check whether something is a local variable like in `MatchLocalNameQ[Evaluate@Module[{a},a],a]` which gives `True`. The second seems to be a "template" for which the local variable has been generated.

Comment: I think it's closely connected to [`MatchLocalNames`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatchLocalNames.html?q=MatchLocalNames), which gives a bit of a hint.

Comment: @corey979 Thanks,that is a reasonable guess(ping  QuantumDot,too)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It checks whether the first argument is a `Module`-localized version of the second:

```
MatchLocalNameQ[x$1, x]
(* True *)
```

`Module` localizes like this:

```
Module[{x}, x]
(* x$29141 *)
```